# Are there quantum-entangled particles in nature?

Tags: quantum-entanglement

Pairs of quantum entangled particles have been created in the lab, and then separated by some distance. But are there any non-manmade occurrences of quantum entanglement between distantly separated particles. Either on earth or elsewhere in the known universe. And how would we detect such entanglement?

Comment: Non-entangled states are pretty much the exception away from zero temperature and single particles.

Comment: One should also add, though, that as soon as more than two sub-systems (a better choice of words than "particle") are entangled, the correlations due to that entanglement are getting weaker quickly, i.e. for most complex systems these correlations are essentially irrelevant. It might be interesting to look at e.g. superconductivity from an entanglement perspective, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we create an entangled state in the lab, really what we are doing is creating a 'known' entangled state that we can then experiment with. As ACuriousMind said in the comment, most of the time things ARE entangled. What is entangled depends on whether the observer has interacted with it or not. If an observer interacts with a dynamic system and then ceases to interact, the observer can say some of the particles in that system are entangled. i say 'dynamic system' because if its a static system then we know its state, by definition.